# How to get texts in iframe using query_selector_all with Playwright

Tags: web-scraping, iframe, playwright, playwright-python

I want to get text data from iframe on a webpage using Playwright with Python. As the data in the iframe, it does not work when I try use page.query_selector_all directly.

For example, below works well, but it's not a solution I want.

```
inner_text = await page.frame_locator('iframe#mypage_frm').locator('//*[@id="List"]').inner_text()
inner_html = await page.frame_locator('iframe#mypage_frm').locator('//*[@id="List"]').inner_html()
print(inner_text)
print(inner_html)
```

I need to use query_selector_all to get data through the loop in the iframe because the data consists of recurring loop. I tried many ideas, but no way work. For example, below does not work.

```
await page.frame_locator('iframe#mypage_frm').query_selector('//*[@id="List"]')
```

Please advise how to use query_selector_all (or just query_selector) in iframe. Thank you.

Comment: Your code uses the right approach (using locators rather than `.query_selector`), just use `.all_text_contents()` rather than `.text_content()` if there are multiple elements. But `#List` is an id, and ids are supposed to be unique, so the question of getting text from multiple id-based elements in a loop doesn't really make sense without clarification. Please share the page itself or a [mcve] representation of the relevant markup and JS behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a selector to return a `ElementHandle` for the frame, and then use the [`content_frame`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-content-frame) method to get a handle to the content frame for the iframe. This [`Frame`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-frame) object supports usage of `query_selector`:

```
iframe_handle = await page.wait_for_selector("#mypage_frm")
iframe = await iframe_handle.content_frame()
await iframe_handle.query_selector('//*[@id="List"]')
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`page.frame`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-frame) to create frame objects